# importing microservice class referance into other microservice application

Tags: microservices

I have two microservice(multidomain) applications.
MS app 1 :
    oauth implementaion. it has User, User Role classes

```
class User {<br/>
       private String userName;<br/>
        private String password;<br/>
   }
```

MS app 2 :
    This application has my custom classes like Employee, EmployeeAssigment.

```
class Employee {<br/>
       private String firstName;<br/>
       private User user<br/>
   }
```

I have to had `User` reference in `Employee` class

My question is, can I have User(from MS app 1) class reference in Employee(MS app 2)?

If YES, will it be a correct Micro Service architecture?

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Microservices allows loose coupling and independently deployable units(services). In the example mentioned, user information can vary between different microservices. A user in User/Profile service can be represented as 'User' whereas the same can be represented as 'Employee' in Employee service or maybe by some other name in another service. It all depends on the context where an Entity belongs. 
If same User class being used in two services, it adds a coupling between them as change in one will affect other. 
A suggestion would be to have different classes as per the service context and communicate between through integration events.